# How do I upgrade my character stuck with level 1 skills?

Tags: paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory

The only place I noticed I can evolve my character if after it dies, so my clone comes with extra points to distribute.

I only used one clone (meaning I'm version 2) but I made it when I was RED, so no extra points to distribute.

Is there a way to gain those points without cloning?

I ask that because it seems that I can only clone myself 4 or 5 times. After that, it's probably game over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to increase skills is with new clones, and yes, you're done after number 6. However, you can buy more clones from the first guy you meet right after you emerge from the cloning vats. Five Bytecoins a pop.